# Can 'nop' instruction save execute time on AArch64?

Tags: performance, assembly, cpu-architecture, arm64

```
 .text
 .globl asm_f1
 .globl asm_f2
 .globl asm_f3
 .globl asm_f4
 .globl asm_f5



 asm_f1:
   mov x0, #1
   movk x0, #1, lsl #16
   movk x0, #1, lsl #32
   ret

 asm_f2:
   nop
   nop
   nop
   ret

 asm_f3:
   mov x0, #1
   movk x0, #1, lsl #16
   nop
   ret

 asm_f4:
   mov x0, #1
   nop
   movk x0, #1, lsl #16
   ret

 asm_f5:
   mov x0, #1
   nop
   nop
   ret
```

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   clock_t start;
   clock_t end;
   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     asm_f1();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("asm_f1 took %ld cycles on avg\n", (end - start) );


   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     asm_f2();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("asm_f2 took %ld cycles on avg\n", (end - start) );


   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     asm_f3();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("asm_f3 took %ld cycles on avg\n", (end - start) );

   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     asm_f4();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("asm_f4 took %ld cycles on avg\n", (end - start) );

   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     asm_f5();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("asm_f5 took %ld cycles on avg\n", (end - start) );
 }
```

```
asm_f1 took 345961 cycles on avg
asm_f2 took 325725 cycles on avg
asm_f3 took 327267 cycles on avg
asm_f4 took 324958 cycles on avg
asm_f5 took 349501 cycles on avg
```

Compared with f1 and f2, it seems that 'nop' will save time than 'mov'. As f3 and f4 just use one 'nop', they are a little bit slower than f2 which is expected.  f5 uses 2 'nop' but it's slower than f3 and f4, how to explain this case?

```
$> lsb_release -a 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

$> uname -p
aarch64
```

Some docs from AArch64 instruction book

> NOP
>
> No Operation does nothing, other than advance the value of the program counter by 4. This instruction can be used for instruction alignment purposes.
>
> The timing effects of including a NOP instruction in a program are not guaranteed. It can increase execution time, leave it unchanged, or even reduce it. Therefore, NOP instructions are not suitable for timing loops.

---

Update:

According to [@Siguza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302862/siguza)'s comment, I changed the loop a little, the performance gap now is more obvious.

```c
void loop(void *f, char *fname) {
   clock_t start;
   clock_t end;
   start = clock();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
     ((void(*)())f)();
   }
   end = clock();
   printf("%s took %ld cycles on avg\n", fname, (end - start) );
 }


 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   loop(asm_f1, "asm_f1");
   loop(asm_f2, "asm_f2");
   loop(asm_f3, "asm_f3");
   loop(asm_f4, "asm_f4");
   loop(asm_f5, "asm_f5");
   return 0;
 }
```

```
asm_f1 took 344089 cycles on avg
asm_f2 took 259436 cycles on avg
asm_f3 took 246766 cycles on avg
asm_f4 took 245166 cycles on avg
asm_f5 took 354827 cycles on avg
```

Comment: "how to explain this case?" - CPU instruction pipelines are strange beasts. Hand-written assembly now often runs worse than llvm/gcc generated binaries because mere mortals cannot reliably anticipate how things like out-of-order-execution and branch-prediction will work-out at the same scale as the latest compilers.

Comment: I feel like instruction caching could _easily_ mess this up. I suggest repeating this test with code that is aligned to the cacheline size of your biggest cache. And I think you wouldn't just have to align the assembly functions, but also put the loop into a separate function that gets passed a function pointer, and make sure the loop function is _not_ inlined.